# My byobu status bar is bugging out?

Tags: byobu

I'm trying to figure out what's going on with my status bar. It's going nuts! Is there any output I should include or anything?

Because it's difficult to describe the problem in mere words, I've made a video recording of exactly what's happening: https://youtu.be/FNDprbWRL8k

I know this is probably a shot in the dark, but it has to affect more than just me, right?